# How can I keep the selections of a multiselect box on a button click in PHP?

Tags: php

I have the below code:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',"1");

    $select = '<select multiple name = "select3[]">';

    $lines = file('/volumes/file-vault-projects/project-list.txt');
    $fifth_column = array();
    foreach ($lines as $line){
        $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $line);
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($parts as $partVal){
            if ((in_array($partVal, $fifth_column) == FALSE) && $count == 4){
                $fifth_column[] = $partVal;
                sort($fifth_column);
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }

    foreach($fifth_column as $value){


        $select .= "<option value='".$value."'>".$value."</option>";
    }

    $select .= '</select>';

    echo $select;





?>
```

On a button click the selections are cleared. How can I keep the options selected? I have managed to keep other things selected but that was in HTML. I am unsure how to do it in PHP.

I have numerous if statements to see if anything has been selected. For example:

```
if($_POST){
    if(isset($_POST['Apply']) && 
      (isset($_POST['Finished']) && $_POST['Finished'] == 'Finished') && 
        !isset($_POST['dates'])&&
       !empty($_POST['select3']) ) {
Apply();
}

function Apply() {

     foreach($_POST['select3'] as $project1) 
     {
       $searchthis = "  finished    ";
       $project = $_POST['select3'];
       $matches = array();
       $handle = @fopen("/volumes/file-vault-projects/project-list.txt", "r");

        if ($handle) {
                        while (!feof($handle)) {
                            $buffer = fgets($handle);
                                if(strpos ($buffer, $project1) &&
                                    strpos($buffer, $searchthis) !== FALSE)
                                    $matches[] = $buffer;

                                }
            fclose($handle);
        }




            foreach ($matches as $child)
            {
             $col1 = explode ("\t", $child);
         echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>',htmlspecialchars($col1[0]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</td><td>', htmlspecialchars($col1[1]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</td><td>', htmlspecialchars($col1[2]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</td><td>', htmlspecialchars($col1[3]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</td><td>', htmlspecialchars($col1[4]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td>';
                    echo '</td><td>', htmlspecialchars($col1[5]). "<br />";
                    echo '</td></tr>';

            }


}
    echo '</table>';
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How are you deciding it is selected?

Comment: Where is the code for your button click?

Comment: By the time the user is clicking on the page, PHP is done. Your question doesn't make sense. Are you asking how to make some of the options already selected when the page is first displayed?

Comment: So when the button is clicked it will check if there are any selections being made, but it clears all the selections when the results are displayed, I want to be able to keep them selection selected. @Barmar

Comment: I have added some more of my code @b0s3

Comment: I have added some more of my code @Ben Pearl Kahan

Comment: Where is the `Apply();` function?

Comment: Are you saving those selections on database or any where?

Comment: added the apply function @BenPearlKahan

Answer (score 0):

If you want the options that were submitted in the form to be pre-selected when the page is redisplayed, add the `selected` attribute to the option based on whether it's in `$_POST['select3']`.

```
foreach ($fifth_column as $value) {
    $selected = (isset($_POST['select3']) && in_array($value, $_POST['select3'])) ? 'selected' : '';
    $select .= "<option value='$value' $selected>$value</option>";
}
```

Comment: It just says :
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in 

Notice: Undefined index: select3 on line 383 @Barmar

Comment: Need to test whether the parameter is set. If they haven't selected anything, the parameter won't be sent.